# Logging does not work

Tags: python, logging

I am using standard logging configurations, set in settings.py file, and accessed in program but I get the error

> error No handlers could be found for logger.

It works when run from the console but does not work when run from Eclipse.

The code is as follows:

```
import logging
from config import settings
logger = logging.getLogger('engine')

class ReplyUser(object):

    def __init__(self):
        logger.info("Initalizes ReplyUser")

    def myfun(self):
        logger.info("Hi")
        print "hi"
```

Comment: The problem is likley to be in you settings.py. Please post that, but make sure to remove any sensitve data.

Answer (score 0):

I am guessing the problem is in the PATH which eclipse is using and it is unable to find settings.py as the handler information is stored in the settings.py file, hence the error.